# Using Ant/Ivy to create pom.xml and pom.properties and embedding them into the jar/war file

Tags: ant, ivy, pom.xml

We use Ant with Ivy and I'd like to embed in our created jars and wars the `pom.xml` and the `pom.properties` file just as you see if you used Maven. Creating a `pom.xml` from the `ivy.xml` file is pretty simple with the `<ivy:makepom>` task. Getting the artifactId and the gorupId can be done via the `<xmlproperty>` task. However, how do I create the `pom.properties` file. Is that necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, while going through the documentation, I found it was a lot easier than I thought. Ivy generates a lot of properties which can be used. I also found that the `pom.xml` file only contains the `groupId`, `artifactId` and the `version`, so it's not that tough to generate.

Here's what I did:

```
<target name="package" depends="compile">

    <!-- Make the pom.xml -->
    <ivy:makepom ivyfile="${ivy.resolved.file}"
        pomfile="${target.dir}/pom.xml"/>

    <!-- Make the pom.properties file -->
    <echo file="${target.dir}/pom.properties">
# Generated by Maven NOT!
# ${build.date}
version=${ivy.revision}
groupId="${ivy.organisation}
artifactId="${ivy.module}
    </echo>

<!-- Build your JAR or whatever -->

    <jar destfile="${target.dir}/{ant.project.name}.jar"
         basedir="${main.destdir}">
         <manifest>
              <section name="Build-Information">
                  <attribute name="Project" value="${env.JOB_NAME}"/>
                  <attribute name="Build-Number" value="${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"/>
                  <attribute name="Build-Date" value="${build.date}"/>
              </section>
         </manifest>
         <zipfileset dir="${target.dir}"
              prefix="$META-INF/maven/${ivy.organisation}/${ivy.module}">
              <include name="pom.xml"/>
              <include name="pom.properties"/>
         </zipfileset>
     </jar>
</target>
```

This helps make using Ivy pretty compatible with Maven.